# Make Player Flash When Hit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my player flash when hit. I have hit detection working. He currently changes to red. I'm wondering how to make the actual flashing occur. Here's a snippet that handles being hit:

```
if(otherObject.CompareTag("Minion")) //hit by minion
    {
        if(hitFromTop(otherObject.gameObject)) //if player jumped on enemy
        {
            otherObject.GetComponent<Minion>().setMoving(false); //stop moving
            playSound(KillEnemySound); //play killing enemy sound
            jump();
            Destroy(otherObject.gameObject); //kill minion

        }
        else //otherwise, enemy hit player
        {
            if(canTakeDamage)
            {
                changeColor(Color.red);
                loseHealth(1); //lose health
                canTakeDamage=false;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f); //delay taking damage repeatedly
                changeColor(Color.white);
                canTakeDamage=true;
            }
            //indicate lost health somehow
        }
```

Currently, the changing to red is constant (not flashing) and temporary, via the `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);`. I could put a couple of these calls, with colour changes in between them, but I was wondering if there was a neater way. I can't be the first one to make something flash in a game.

EDIT: I've added Heisenbug's Flash() code as follows:

```
IEnumerator FlashPlayer(float time, float intervalTime)
{
    canTakeDamage=false;
    float elapsedTime = 0f;
    int index = 0;

    while(elapsedTime < time )
    {
        Debug.Log("Elapsed time = " + elapsedTime + " < time = " + time + " deltaTime " + Time.deltaTime);
        mat.color = colors[index % 2];
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        index++;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(intervalTime);
    }
    canTakeDamage=true;
}
```

and it is called here:

```
void loseHealth(int damage)
{
    //irrelevant details omitted for brevity
            //the "if" checks if the player has run out of health, should not affect the else because this method is called from OnTriggerEnter...see below...
    else
    {
        StartCoroutine(FlashPlayer (1.5f, 0.5f));
    }
}
```

and here is where THAT is called (in OnTriggerEnter):

```
    if(otherObject.CompareTag("Minion")) //hit by minion
    {
        if(hitFromTop(otherObject.gameObject)) //if player jumped on enemy
        {
            //irrelevant to the problem
        }
        else //otherwise, enemy hit player
        {
            if(canTakeDamage)
            {
                     loseHealth(1); 
            }
            //indicate lost health somehow
        }
    }
```

The problem now is that the Flash never stops. It should stop when elapsedTime reaches 1.5f, as I specified, but because it is only incrementing by small amounts (in Time.deltaTime) then it doesn't reach 1.5f for a very long time. Is there anything I've left out that should make it reach 1.5f faster, or is there another number I can pick that I can use accurately to act as a stopping point? The numbers for elapsedTime tend to be: 0, 0.02, 0.03693, 0.054132, etc. very small, so nothing I can really pick from here.

Comment: consider posting an SSCCE: http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had a chance to do that yet. I'll try as soon as I get the opportunity.

Answer (score 3):

The following code may be what you are looking for. The object should flash for the total amount of `time` changing its color after `intervalTime`

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FlashingObject : MonoBehaviour {

    private Material mat;
    private Color[] colors = {Color.yellow, Color.red};

    public void Awake()
    {

        mat = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;

    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine(Flash(5f, 0.05f));
    }

    IEnumerator Flash(float time, float intervalTime)
    {
        float elapsedTime = 0f;
        int index = 0;
        while(elapsedTime < time )
        {
            mat.color = colors[index % 2];

            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            index++;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(intervalTime);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is working so far. The only thing is, it's not actually stopping after `time` has passed. I'm going to throw in some debug statements, but any idea why this might be? Note that I'm not calling the coroutine from Start like you did, I'm calling it from my `loseHealth(1)` function you see in my code snippet above (I've removed everything else from that condition other than the call to `loseHealth(1)`).

Comment: is loseHealth called inside Update or similar methods?

Comment: No, it's called inside onTriggerEnter only (unless that counts as a similar method...).

Comment: No.OnTriggerEnter should be called once per collision. Perhaps you are calling Flash method multiple times, because otherwise it would end correctly. I suggest you to put some breakpoints inside Flash method and examine the stacktrace or use some print to identify the problem. The bug is somewhere else.

Comment: I'm calling like this `StartCoroutine(Flash (1.5f, 0.5f));`

Comment: I have a print statement printing the elapsed time on every loop (the while loop in Flash()). It prints times like 0, 0.02, 0.0366, 0.03535, etc. Which seems to indicate that Time.deltaTime is incrementing it by very small amounts, and it's never actually reaching 1.5f.

Comment: The time elapsed it's wrong. It's not increasing. IF Flash is called only once (check it please, I'm not sure about that since I don't see the complete code) than elapsedTime must increase meanwhile 0.03535 is less than 0.0366.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28541/discussion-between-heisenbug-and-rar)

Answer (score -1):

The answer above is great, but it does not stop flashing, because it takes far too long for the float to reach 5f.

The trick is to set the first parameter in the **Flash** function to something smaller, like 1f, instead of 5f. Take this script, and attach it to any game object. It will flash between yellow and red for about 2.5 seconds, then stop.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FlashingObject : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Material _mat;
    private Color[]  _colors = { Color.yellow, Color.red };
    private float    _flashSpeed = 0.1f;
    private float _lengthOfTimeToFlash = 1f;

    public void Awake()
    {

        this._mat = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;

    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Flash(this._lengthOfTimeToFlash, this._flashSpeed));
    }

    IEnumerator Flash(float time, float intervalTime)
    {
        float elapsedTime = 0f;
        int index         = 0;
        while (elapsedTime < time)
        {
            _mat.color = _colors[index % 2];

            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            index++;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(intervalTime);
        }
    }
}
```